# TV show from 8-9 years ago from Cartoon Network where they transformed using small bricks

Tags: story-identification, cartoon

One of them had blue hair they transformed using a weird light in the back of a pawn shop I think it was set in Japan it came on early morning Saturday.

Comment: Who were they and what did they transform into?

Comment: did it look japanese made and dubbed over? (ie anime?)